# Issue when export to csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, export-to-csv

when export to csv a numeric need all values to be exported as a string including numeric value have value like this 012546320 would be like this 12546320 after exported to csv

need to export all value as a string to avoid this problem

-df.to_csv('hhh.csv')
i have tried to path str to float_format but it didn't work, also i search on google and here but didn't find any a solution

-df.to_csv('hhh.csv',float_format='str')

this the data before export to csv
[image]

​

this is the data after the 0 is removed, i didn't want to remove it
[image]

Comment: The first step is to figure out at what stage the zeroes go missing — when writing the CSV file, or when importing it into whatever your screenshot is from. Look at the file with a text editor. Are the zeroes there?

Comment: thank you, the zero is exported but when open file in excel it droped, it is excel problem,

Answer (score 0):

If need remove `0` for all strings columns from left side use:

```
cols = df.select_dtypes(object).columns
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.str.lstrip('0'))
```

Comment: Nah, the 0 is deleted after exported, i didn't want to delete it

Answer (score 0):

Try dtype=str or maybe converting first to exel pd.ExcelWriter would help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).